# Sybase table export

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am trying to export sybase table to text file.
I am issing following script in SQL Advantage.

```
SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE id = 1;
OUTPUT TO 'name.txt'
FORMAT TEXT;
```

I am receiving :

```
Server Message: Number 102, Severity 15
Server 'SERVER3', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about this feature in SQL Advantage.

Also I think that SQL Advantage is not the best tool for exporting.
Try free isql replacement - sqsh. http://www.sqsh.org/

It's very easy to export to text file with sqsh (http://www.sqsh.org/sqsh_features.html#Pipes)

```
   1> select * from sysobjects
   2> go 2>/dev/null >/tmp/objects.txt
```

Sqsh on windows - http://www.sqsh.org/sqsh_nt.html